# Pass HTML form data in a PHP file to ONE OF 3 other PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a website with a simple login interface. The user can log in as one of 3 different users types, A B and C using 1 form. The code inside the form for handling this is:

```
                    <input type="radio" name="user_type" value="a" id="a">
                    <label for="a">A</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="user_type" value="b" id="b">
                    <label for="b">B</label>

                    <input type="radio" name="user_type" value="c" id="c">
                    <label for="c">C</label>
```

Depending on the user type, the login page should redirect the user to one of three PHP files on click of the form submit button. I know in PHP you can use

```
<form method="post" action="otherFile.php">
```

In the login page for leading to one other file. And use

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    echo $firstname . "<br/>";
    echo $lastname;
}
?>
```

In otherFile.php to retrieve form data. But I want to do this for one of three PHP files, depending on the user's selection of user_type, and

```
<form method="post" action="otherFile.php|otherFile2.php|otherFile3.php">
```

clearly doesn't work.

Comment: You can use sessions to store your data for use later in other places.

Comment: @Caelan I have this at the top of my code:

<?php
   ob_start();
   session_start();
?>

But I'm not sure how to use this to keep data for later use.

Comment: See answer :) @jvnna

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SESSION` to store data for use in other areas of your site.

To simplify it, you could do something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname']; // store firstname, lastname as sessions
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
```

And then, inside of another page, you can call these sessions to output:

```
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
print("$firstname"); // will print the first name.
```

I hope this helps :)

**EDIT**: Before you create a `$_SESSION` and try to print it into another page, create a **core.php** page and `include` it into both **page1.php** & **page2.php**

Inside of your **core.php** script, you need to start up a session, like so:

```
session_start();
```

Once you have included the **core.php** file into both of your pages, try printing out the desired `$_SESSION` variable again.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks

Comment: @jvnna if this worked for you, please consider selecting it as correct and / or upvoting it :)

Comment: I'm still having problems. I have `<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user']; // store firstname, lastname as sessions
   $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']; 
?>` in login.php and in user_type1.php I have `<?php
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    print("$user"); // will print the first name.
?>` but it doesn't print anything on user_type1.php when I run the code

Comment: Did you remember to `session_start();` on the new page?

Comment: I didn't, but I just added it. It still does not print anything when updated

Comment: Ok, so I've just updated it for you. Check to see if this solves your problem. :)

Comment: It does not work still. I added an echo statement just after declaring session variables in page1.php to verify PHP is running correctly, and it is. I tried to pass `include core.php;
 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["user"] = "Green";
   $_SESSION["password"] = "red"; ` (regular strings instead of form data) and it still will not pass the variables to page2.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114697/discussion-between-caelan-grgurovic-and-jvnna).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is you want, but you can create a single php, and if is a value, require it using include or require functions.

For example, processor.php

```
    <? 
$user_type = $_POST["user_type"];
switch($user_type) {
    case "a":
        require_once 'otherFile.php';
        break;
    case "b":
        require_once 'otherFile2.php';
        break;
    case "c":
        require_once 'otherFile3.php';
        break;
    default:
        die("Not allowed");
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#myForm").submit(function( event ) {
    var radio = jQuery('input[name=user_type]:checked', this).val();
    if(radio == 'a')
        this.action = 'otherFile.php';
    else if(radio == 'b')
        this.action = 'otherFile2.php';
    else if(radio == 'c')
        this.action = 'otherFile3.php';
    else
        return false;
});
</script>
```

You form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="user_type" value="a" id="a">
    <label for="a">A</label>

    <input type="radio" name="user_type" value="b" id="b">
    <label for="b">B</label>

    <input type="radio" name="user_type" value="c" id="c">
    <label for="c">C</label>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: But I also want to save the text/radio/dropdown form entries from my login page and bring them to the other pages. I'm not familiar with JS/jQuery but I don't think your code does that